# Make dnsmasq reject some names

Tags: dnsmasq

I'd like to setup dnsmasq as DNS-only server for blocking certain domains. But instead of having it return `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` or such, I'd like it to respond with a `No such name.` just as if the name does not exist at all.

How to I filter certain domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make dnsmasq authoritative for those domains with the `--auth-zone` option, and simply not add any DNS records for those domains.

Comment: You can't configure it inside `dnsmasq.conf`, can you? Adding a lot of hosts using the command line parameters seems not to be a practicable.

Comment: All dnsmasq command line options can also be used as configuration parameters.

Comment: OK, works. Although this approach seems quite contraintuitive to me.